# FmodEx error with system->init()

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fmod

I am using FmodEx (Fmod give me problems in Ubuntu) and I have the next problem.

```
System_Create(&system);
system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0)
```

I use this call in the SoundEngine init, but when I run the code, it terminate when It do the method init of System. I cant get the FMOD_RESULT because it never end correctly

Anyonw knows what is the problem?

Thanks for your time^^

EDIT: I print the result of System_Create and give me an error

```
FMOD_ERR_INVALID_PARAM
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use System_Create before

```
FMOD::System     *system; //handle to FMOD engine
//init FMOD
    FMOD::System_Create(&system);// create an instance of the game engine
    system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);// initialise the game engine with 32 channels
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to put in my topic. I have this

System_Create(&system);
system->init(32, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, 0);

But I also give me error

Comment: try that : gcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lfmod-3.75 testfmod.c -o testfmod

Comment: I am using Eclipse, and I dont have fmod-3.75

Comment: what is the version?? can you tries that FMOD_System_Create(&system);
FMOD_System_Init(system, 1, FMOD_INIT_NORMAL, NULL);

Comment: I get the last version of FMOD EX from www.fmod.org. I think is the 4.44